# jQuery: If URL hash is "x" do this?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out a simple script:

If the URL hash is #commercial (like http://domain.com/#commercial) -> then "call a trigger", but I don't really know how to get this started.

Thoughts?

Comment: `location.hash.substr(1)`

Comment: Hi @Stephanie please accept the answers that the problems for the questions you ask (generally). It helps this website to function.

Comment: Hi scrowler. I'm not sure what you mean? Would you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, you can get the hash value of URL using [`.hash`](http://devdocs.io/dom/urlutils.hash):

```
window.location.hash
```

Comment: Hi there! Okay, but how do I get so that "if this hash name is #commercial" do this? Would it be something like: "if window.location.hash == commercial { "

Comment: `if ( win...hash === '#commercial' ) {`